# 2-d chart which is dependent from one value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Lets say that I have table in excel:

```
ID money
1  500
2  750
3  100
4  300
5  450
6  400
```

Now of course I can make histogram. But we have one parameter more. Lets say `money_val=500`. Now we make two histogram. One for all value which column money is greater than 500 :

```
ID money
1  500
2  750
```

and second for all value which column is smaller than 500:

```
ID money
3  100
4  300
5  450
6  400
```

But now, if we change `money_val`, these two histograms will be also changed.

Do you have any idea how can I get this? Of course, we can use VBA.

Comment: If your data is contained in an Excel table, and your chart is based on the table, the filtering can be made using column header filter - No VBA required. For creating tables in Excel, see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Create-an-Excel-table-33d08e18-fa0f-40fe-8af3-5683b034ec42

Answer (score 0):

> I found that you're right about that filters on tables also not refreshed after a cell value changed.

The best solution for this is -*In Office 2013*- using **`Slicer`** -*I'm not sure it is in Office 2010*-.
you can add a column to your table that return just `true` or `false` by some formula like `= [@ColA] < 500`.
Now you can Add your `Slicer` -*from Insert/Filters/Slicer*- and select `result` column.
Now you have a Slicer with just two value `true` and `false`, that you can instead of re-filtering your Table; just click on true.

I hope this can be helpful, but I'm nit sure ;).